# Java8 Stream compiler message -- local variable must be final or effectively final

Tags: java, eclipse, java-stream

I have a little problem. When I write this for loop, the variable `i` in f.getAnswerScore().get(i).... is underlined with error message : - Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or 
     effectively final. Does this have something to do with streams? Maybe streams can't be used in loops?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    correct = active.stream()
        .filter(f -> f.getAnswerScore().get(i).getStatus().equals(AnswerStatus.ANSWERED_CORRECT))
        .count();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like anonymous inner classes, lambda expressions can only access local variables if they are `final` or "effectively final" (Java 8 or higher; not `final` but never changed once assigned).

This is covered by [the JLS, Section 15.27.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2):

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in a lambda expression must either be declared `final` or be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.
>
> Any local variable used but not declared in a lambda body must be definitely assigned (§16 (Definite Assignment)) before the lambda body, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Similar rules on variable use apply in the body of an inner class (§8.1.3). The restriction to effectively final variables prohibits access to dynamically-changing local variables, whose capture would likely introduce concurrency problems. Compared to the final restriction, it reduces the clerical burden on programmers.

Declare a `final` variable equal to `i` and use it.

```
for(int i = 0; i< 10; i++){
     final int j = i;
     correct = active
         .stream()
         .filter(f-> f.getAnswerScore().get(j).getStatus().equals(AnswerStatus.ANSWERED_CORRECT))
         .count();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

rgettman's answer is a workaround. You never use `correct` inside the loop, so why bother assigning to it 10 times rather than running it just once with `i = 9`?

The answer is that you're probably doing something else with `correct` that you're not showing us, and a thorough answer to the question would probably require us to know what that is. Because it's quite unlikely that a C-style for loop like you've written is actually the best/most elegant solution to the problem you're trying to solve.

One possibility is to collect all the `correct` values in another stream:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).map(i ->
  active
  .stream()
  .filter(f ->
     f.getAnswerScore()
      .get(i)
      .getStatus()
      .equals(AnswerStatus.ANSWERED_CORRECT)
  )
  .count()
)
```

Of course, you might want to do something else entirely, there's no way for us to know.