# Arrays as local variable - do not follow Definite Assignment rule in Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Have seen following threads:

[Java8 Stream compiler message -- local variable must be final or effectively final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777192/java8-stream-compiler-message-local-variable-must-be-final-or-effectively-fin)

[Variable assignment in lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004411/variable-assignment-in-lambda-expression)

According to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but
>   not declared in a lambda expression must either be declared final or
>   be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where
>   the use is attempted.
>
> Any local variable used but not declared in a lambda body must be
>   definitely assigned (§16 (Definite Assignment)) before the lambda
>   body, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Similar rules on variable use apply in the body of an inner class
>   (§8.1.3). The restriction to effectively final variables prohibits
>   access to dynamically-changing local variables, whose capture would
>   likely introduce concurrency problems. Compared to the final
>   restriction, it reduces the clerical burden on programmers.

Is `arrays` an exception to **rule** **[1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.2)**?

A sample program that validates javadoc:

```
List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,45,678); 
final int v = 2;
li.stream().filter(e-> e!=v).map(e->e).forEach(System.out::println);
v= 5;
```

> compilation error at line **v=5;** , obviously

**A sample snippet that is violating the final assignment rule:**

```
List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,45,678); 
final int[] v = {2};
li.stream().filter(e-> e!=v[0]).map(e->e).forEach(System.out::println);
v[0]= 5;
```

---

**Output:**

```
3

45

678
```

**Above snippet is giving no compilation error, am i missing something??**

Comment: You are not assigning to `v`, hence, you are not violating the final assignment rule. Assigning to `v[0]` is an entirely different thing. It’s not different to `final Point p = new Point();`, followed by assigning `p.x=4;` and accessing `p.x` in a lambda expression.

Comment: @CommonMan - Voting to close as *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.*

Comment: You need to do `v = someotherarrray` to violate the final *assignment*. Updating `v[0]` does not update any assigment bit the object itself.

Comment: @Holger , i got your point. +1

Comment: @nullpointer, i thought it might help someone so i put it here, i got the concept bro, wanted to save time of people who in future stumble upon this.

Comment: @Sylwester, i am able to violate it now. thanks+1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case `v` is variable of type `int`, here value of `v` is 2 and it is `final` variable. when you try to assign 5 it is giving error because you can't change `final` variable value(Working as expected).

Comes to second case, `v` in not a variable of type `int`, it is an `array`. In Java arrays are objects, so here `v` is a reference. Generally a reference refers to an object and contains the address of the object. When your trying to do `v[0] = 5` here your changing the value inside the object but not the value of the reference. If you try to do `v = new int[1]` or `v={5}` then you will get compilation error

Comment: Yeah, @Sat i understood your point, it was slightly confusing in beginning so i thought to put it up here, may be in future someone will stumble upon this and could be benefited from this.